# Managing Layouts in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, layout

I am new to `iOS` development, I have a solid background on JAVA Swing and Windows Applications.
I want to learn how to do layouting in `iOS`? I guess `iOS` doesn't have **"Layout Managers"** like in Java Swing..
The only way to develop `UI` is specifying size and positions for every controller?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[First Read This Official Documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW1)

Also it may be helpful for you.

[image]

Here **Autoresizing** mask and its **Description**

1) `UIViewAutoresizingNone`
The view does not autoresize. (This is the default value.)

2) `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`
The view’s height changes when the superview’s height changes. If this constant is not included, the view’s height does not change.

3) `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`
The view’s width changes when the superview's width changes. If this constant is not included, the view’s width does not change.

4) `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin`
The distance between the view’s left edge and the superview’s left edge grows or shrinks as needed. If this constant is not included, the view’s left edge remains a fixed distance from the left edge of the superview.

5) `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin`
The distance between the view’s right edge and the superview’s right edge grows or shrinks as needed. If this constant is not included, the view’s right edge remains a fixed distance from the right edge of the superview.

6) `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin`
The distance between the view’s bottom edge and the superview’s bottom edge grows or shrinks as needed. If this constant is not included, the view’s bottom edge remains a fixed distance from the bottom edge of the superview.

7) `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin`
The distance between the view’s top edge and the superview’s top edge grows or shrinks as needed. If this constant is not included, the view’s top edge remains a fixed distance from the top edge of the superview.

For more information read this [documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html)

Comment: thank you for your helps... I realize approach to ui development in mobile is totally different from desktop..
Is Autoresizing related with AutoLayout? I dont want to use AutoLayout beacause of not compatible with ios4 and earlier..

Comment: The link at the top is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right there is nothing like Layout Managers in iOS SDK.

But it is not hard to manage layout in Xcode.

With use of storyboard and size inspector it become more easy. 
and iOS 6 auto-layout make is easier for different size view.

I found something like layout manager but I dont know what exactly it is and how to use.

You can have a look : [RKLayout](https://github.com/rkovacevic/RKLayout)