# Can't adjust autoresizing mask for viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-5, autoresizingmask

I'm trying to adjust my app to iPhone 5, but I ran into some difficulties.

[image]

1. The header of the ContainerViewController (always stays on top)
2. The ContainerViewController that holds the other ViewControllers
3. SidebarViewController
4. ContentViewController

So, the container contains the header, sidebar and content views. Inside content view I have UINavigationController. My problem is when I use iPhone 5 it changes all of the application looks, even when I use Autoresizing Mask, it looks bad and not on the correct position, I think that it's maybe because of the container header that I created.

I set it like this:

[image]

And this is an example of the view that holds UIScrollView and UIImageView as background: (pay attention to the bottom of the UIScrollView and the UIImageView, it pushes them outside of the view.

iPhone 4:

[image]

iPhone 5:

[image]

This is the first time i'm using Autoresizing mask, so please be patient with me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: put relavent code here and also check...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060391/managing-layouts-in-ios/15060789#15060789

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am not going to answer this deep down. You have set the auto resizing  wrong.
Here are things that will work. To deal with iPhone5 you just need `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight` as `autoresizingMask`

If you want to know properly about Auto-resizing read through [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html)

[image: For Container View]
For Container

[image: For Header]
For Header

[image: For Content View]
For Content

[image: For SideBar]
For Side Bar